# The function evaluation requires all threads to run in VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net

When I try to get get the values from Orders table it will show this message in result instead of Orders table values

```
Private ReadOnly db As New DataModel
Public Property GridData As Object
Function Index() As ActionResult

    'BindDataSource()
    Dim DataSorce = db.orders.ToList()
    GridData = From orders In db.orders Select New With {orders.OrderID, orders.EmployeeID, orders.CustomerID}
    'DataSorce.getAllRecords()
    'Dim contracts = datas
    Return View(GridData)
End Function
```

Comment: That's a *debugger* message, which says that the *debugger* can't do what you asked it to do while the application is paused. That's not a problem. The *real* problem is that the code is trying to load *all* the data with `orders.ToList()` when it only needs three fields, `GridData` has the wrong type and too wide a scope. All this code should be replaced with `Dim query=From orders in db.orders select...... Dim contracts= query.ToList() Return View(contracts)`

Comment: [Why do we get “The function evaluation requires all threads to run”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/).